# Python Spark-Streaming get n max keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am doing a simple wordcount with Spark Streaming. How do I get the n most used words, or in other words, get the first n keys with the highest values?

Here is my code so far:

```
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
.map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
.reduceByKeyAndWindow(lambda a, b: a+b, lambda a, b: a-b, 30, 2)

output = counts.map(lambda (a, b):(b, a)).transform(lambda rdd: rdd.sortByKey(ascending=False)).map(lambda (a, b):(b, a))
```

Which already sorts the list in descending order, now I need to just take the top n elements. There is examples out there how to do it in Scala, which uses rdd.take() and then filter the rdd based on list.contains. But Python doesn't have list.contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `Python` to explore the `List`. Seems you have not explored much in python. In `Python`you can perform `List` operations.

```
If value in Mylist:
#Do your action
```

If you wanted to take N number of element from `List`

```
list[:10]
```

will give you the first 10 elements of this list using slicing.

[Python List document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Please have look on this answer [pythons-slice-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)